# How do I create multiple screens/views using phoneGap?

Tags: ios, css, cordova, mobile

I'm building a reading application and want to try using phoneGap for the first time. I'm comfortable with HTML, CSS and JS, but don't have much experience with xCode. Let's say that for this reading application on the home screen I have a button. When the user clicks the button I would like it to redirect to another screen/view. Would the correct way of doing this be just to create a link on the home page and when they click it redirect them to another view? I don't think I would need another model or controller, but I'm not certain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best way to implement multiple 'views' in a Phonegap application is to use the 'single page application' design pattern.

Phonegap applications are native applications that set a native webview as the default and ONLY native view for the application. Though you can use plugins to implement other types of native views, a basic Phonegap application only uses one native view.

You are able to program with HTML/CSS/JS within the webview anyway you prefer.

If you are not familiar with the single page website design pattern here is a basic explanation:

- One single html file
- Use `div` containers with specific ids to show and hide content
- Ajax requests are used to manipulate data within the application (so no page refreshes are needed)

Comment: Ok so let's say I had an app with 10 chapters, but I only want to show one chapter at a time. You are saying to show the first chapter (hide the rest) then when I click on the second chapter, show that one and hide the rest. Correct?

Comment: That is correct. There are some JS based templating libs that can help with this, I suggest HandleBars http://handlebarsjs.com/, but just google for `javascript template framework`. Using one of these frameworks can improve the performance of your single page app.

Comment: Awesome. Dawson, I have a couple more questions do you mind if I email you? You have been really helpful.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize it was set to private: dawson <at> dawsonloudon {dot} com